# Push PyCharm file to GitHub

Tags: github, pycharm

this is my 1st post. I'm in Python and R courses and cannot figure out how to push a file to from pycharm to github. Do I need to commit the file first before pushing it?

Comment: Git never pushes files. It only pushes commits. Yes, you need to commit the file before pushing.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For pushing your changes from pycharm to GitHub
Find the terminal option at the bottom left and click on this and use below commands

```
git add.
git commit -m "put your message"
git push origin <branch name>
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This does help! I'm in my master's program and learning so this is all brand new to me.